# custom sized Tabular: Align text vertically to the top

Tags: tables, align, vertical-alignment

I want to make a two column list with non-manual multi-line support without any special packages. This is as best as I got it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{0.05\textwidth}  m{0.85\textwidth}} 
    Text & \textbf{Apple Bananas} Monkey Keyboard Great
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
        \item This is a very long text that contains different letters, words and probably some typos. Go on and on and on.
        \item Another great text.
    \end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample pdf]

As you can see the content of the left column is not vertically aligned to the top. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: To make this posting more useful for future readers, it would be helpful if you made the code minimalist: AFAICT, the only package that needs to be loaded is `array` (since you're using tne `m` column type). Without the code clutter, future readers will have a better chance to figure out how the proposed solution works. Please fix.

Comment: I've removed the `align` tag.  It applies explicitly to a mathematical display environment defined in `amsmath`, and isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced

```latex
\begin{tabular}{m{0.05\textwidth}  m{0.85\textwidth}}
```

with

```latex
\begin{tabular}{p{0.05\textwidth}  p{0.85\textwidth}}
```